# Loaded Records not showing in view

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jboss7.x, conversation-scope

So to make it relatively simple: I have some Primefaces-Page, which is supposed to represent database records in a table-structure.

I keep these records in a `List<Customer>` which resides in a `@ConversationScoped` backing bean. I have verified via debugging, that the List **gets correctly filled with records from the Database** (hibernate db FWIW). This is accomplished with the help of a "businessInterface" Distributor class, that is in fact nothing but a decoupling mask for (Database)Service-Classes.

As mentioned, I have verified that the Database, as well as the Distributor correctly return the expected values. Unfortunately in the View there are **no records present** and instead the `emptyMessage` is displayed.

The application is running on a jBoss 7.1.1-Final Application Server.

For better readability I have excluded the `h:head`, as well as `h:body`, `ui:composition`, `ui:define` and `h:form` around the provided code, as well as shortened the columns to the two different usages (property display and action exposition)

The View (shortened and truncated):

```
<ui:define name="inhalt">
    <p:growl id="msgGrowl" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" />
    <h:form onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {return false; }">
        <p:dataTable var="customeritem" id="customerTable"
            rowkey="#{customeritem.id}" value="#{customerListController.customerList}"
            paginator="true" rows="13" autoUpdate="true" 
            filteredValue="#{customerListController.filteredCustomers}" 
            emptyMessage="no customers found!" 
            sortFunction="#{customerListController.filteredCustomers}">

            <p:column sortBy="name" filterBy="name" headerText="Kunde"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{customeritem.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:commandButton value="Neuer Kunde"
                        action="${customerListController.addCustomer()}"
                        icon="ui-icon-plus" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandButton id="doViewDetailsButton" icon="ui-icon-clipboard"
                action="${customerListController.viewDetails(customeritem.getId())}" />
                <p:tooltip for="doViewDetailsButton" value="Details ansehen" />

            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

The Backing Bean:

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class CustomerListController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5961625401284927892L;

    private List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    private List<Customer> filteredCustomers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    @Inject
    CustomerEditController customerEditController;

    @Inject
    CustomerDetailsController customerDetailsController;

    @Inject
    CustomerDistributor businessInterface;

    public String addCustomer() {
        return editCustomer(0l);
    }

    public String editCustomer(long customerId) {
        setFilteredCustomers(null);
        customerEditController.recieveCustomerById(customerId);
        return Pages.CUSTOMER_EDIT;
    }

    public String viewDetails(long customerId) {
        setFilteredCustomers(null);
        customerDetailsController.recieveCustomerById(customerId);
        return Pages.CUSTOMER_DETAILS;
    }

    public String deleteCustomer(long customerIdToDelete) {
        businessInterface.delete(customerIdToDelete);
        setFilteredCustomers(null);
        fillCustomerList();
        return Pages.CUSTOMER_LIST;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void fillCustomerList() {
        customerList.clear();
        customerList.addAll(businessInterface.loadAll());

    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        return customerList;
    }

    public List<Customer> getFilteredCustomers() {
        return filteredCustomers;
    }

    public void setFilteredCustomers(List<Customer> filteredCustomers) {
        this.filteredCustomers = filteredCustomers;
    }
}
```

This **used to work**, when I had the Backing Bean in `@SessionScoped`, but as that required hackish workarounds to produce intuitive (and expected) behavior I decided to move the Backing Bean to a smaller scope. I therefore chose the `@ConversationScoped`, because the BackingBean needs to stay longer than the request lifecycle... (Also running a query against a db for every request is damn expensive...)

A short explanation on the `CustomerEditController` and `CustomerDetailsController`. They are the responsible ones for Editing and Showing further information on the single records if they are requested by clicking one of the Buttons.

The non-working stuff is the `@PostConstruct public void fillCustomerList()`. **Everything else works as expected**...

If you need any further information, please ask, I will provide context as needed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a successful workaround for this, but it's **extremely hackish** and I really dislike the approach, as it introduces additional behavior in a getter. I modified the Backing Bean as follows:

```
public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    if (customerList.size() == 0) {
        fillCustomerList();
    }
    return customerList;
}
```

But let me state this again,

#### this is definitely not the desired behavior and not a good approach at solving this problem.

### EDIT:

I found a different fix after a little more digging and a lucky link. I modified the backing bean as follows:

```
@Inject
Conversation conversation;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if(conversation.isTransient()) {
        conversation.end();
    }
    conversation.setTimeout(120000);
    conversation.start();
}
```

and now It works even without the hackish behavior in the getter (as demonstrated above).